# Kubuntu update-grub not updating UEFI

Tags: grub, kubuntu

I can't figure out why the command `sudo update-grub` does not update my menu. The system is UEFI. The menu is never changed. This used to work fine until I booted into Ubuntu (sd5). I am thinking it did something and changed the menu to its own grub but can't fix it to use my own from Kubuntu on sd6.

Here is the command output:

```
~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Linux Mint 20 Ulyana (20) on /dev/sdb4
Found Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sdb5
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Here is the grub menu
[image]

Here are the configurations

```
$ efibootmgr -v 
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0007,0000,000C,000D,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,4d15df2f-e75f-4912-bcba-a62186e4263e,0x12c800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...3................
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive     BBS(129,,0x0)
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)
Boot0003* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)
Boot0007* ubuntu        HD(3,GPT,ae44ef90-80c1-47ed-aa64-0491ca100023,0x41d59800,0x100800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000C* UEFI: IP4 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(448a5b42a3ce,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot000D* UEFI: IP6 Qualcomm Atheros PCIe Network Controller    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(448a5b42a3ce,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
```

Here are my partitions:

```
Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 250069680 sectors, 119.2 GiB

.....
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1230847   600.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2         1230848         1845247   300.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1845248         2107391   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   4         2107392       250068991   118.2 GiB   0700  Basic data partition


Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
....
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      1104517119   526.7 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   2      1923717120      1953523711   14.2 GiB    2700  Basic data partition
   3      1104517120      1105567743   513.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   4      1105567744      1358393343   120.6 GiB   8300  
   5      1881108480      1923717119   20.3 GiB    8300  
   6      1358393344      1881108479   249.3 GiB   8300
```

Comment: You have two menu systems, UEFI & grub. The sudo update-grub only updates grub menu, but not UEFI settings. And all Ubuntu, official flavors of Ubuntu and some non-official flavors use "ubuntu" entry in UEFI. Then grub menu has the other installs. So what menu do you want to update? It looks like grub has multiple installs?

Comment: The Ubuntu UEFI as in the grub menu image above, What are the steps? Can't I use Grub Config? -Thanks

Comment: You show multiple Linux installs. So are you updating one install, but default boot is really a different install? You have multiple grub installs, one per system, but only one is controlling boot. The grub that controls boot should be the system you use as your primary system.